# LogParser Out_RowNumber() and Order By

Tags: logparser

I'm trying to parse log with LogParser. Here is my current request :

```
"select TOP 30 OUT_ROW_NUMBER() AS POSITION, cs-uri-stem, count(*) as Requests INTO MY_TABLE from myIisLog.log WHERE sc-status >= 500 GROUP BY cs-uri-stem ORDER BY Requests DESC" -i:IISW3C -o:SQL -createTable:OFF -oConnString:"driver={sql server native client 10.0};server=MyServer;database=MyDB;uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;"
```

I want to have the top 30 requests on error along with their respective count and position in this standing. The problem is that [OUT_ROW_NUMBER](http://logparserplus.com/Functions#function_OUT_ROW_NUMBER)  operates BEFORE the order by, resulting in wrong results.

Here is the output :

> 4 /TheUriWithTheMostErrors.html 38
>
> 2 /TheSecondUri.html 4
>
> 3 /TheThirdUri.html 3
>
> ...

Is it possible to have both out_row_number and order by working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not; OUT_ROW_NUMBER is invoked *before* the ORDER_BY clause. There is actually nothing that comes to mind to sequentially ID the output records *after* ORDER_BY.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I worked around this problem by using the false data given by OUT_ROW_NUMBER() in my table Primary Key (the goal is not to use the cs-uri-stem and cs-uri-query in my PK) and computing the real order afterwards.

Comment: That's exactly what OUT_ROW_NUMBER stands for - a way to uniquely ID each output record.